# Simple Map Plotting Issue

Tags: c++

i've coded a simple map plotting program but there some error which i can't identify.

1. The bug only occur when X coordinate is positive, its ok when its a negative value.
2. Why is there a last column of dots printed when my range is 11 only?

Here's the code:

```
int xRange = 11;
int yRange = 11;
string _space = "   ";
string _star = " * ";

for( int x = xRange; x > 0; x-- )
{
    for( int y = 0; y < yRange; y++ )
    {
        int currentX = x - 6;
        int currentY = y - 5;

        //demo input
        int testX = 2; //<----------ERROR for +ve int, correct for -ve
        int testY = -4; //<-------- Y is working ok for +ve and -ve int

        //Print x-axis
        if( currentY == 0 )
        {
            if( currentX < 0 )
                cout << currentX << " ";
            else
                cout << " " << currentX << " ";
        }
        //Print y-axis
        if( currentX == 0 )
        {
            if( currentY < 0 )
                cout << currentY << " ";
            else
                //0 printed in x axis already
                if( currentY != 0 )
                    cout << " " << currentY << " ";
        }
        else if( currentY == testX and currentX == testY )
            cout << _star;
        else
            cout << " . ";
    }
    //print new line every completed row print
    cout << endl;
}
```

The ouput for demo input (x: 2, y: -4): ( it shows x at 3 which is wrong )

```
 .  .  .  .  .  5  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  4  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  3  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  2  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  . 
-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5 
 .  .  .  .  . -1  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . -2  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . -3  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . -4  .  .  *  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . -5  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

The output for demo input (x: -2, y: 4):

```
 .  .  .  .  .  5  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  *  .  4  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  3  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  2  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  . 
-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5 
 .  .  .  .  . -1  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . -2  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . -3  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . -4  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . -5  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Can anyone help to identify the two problem in my code? thanks.

Comment: You compare `currentY == testX and currentX == testY`, is this a mixup or intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if( currentY == testX and currentX == testY )`

That doesn't look right. Shouldn't you be comparing X to X and Y to Y?

Upon closer look, it's all even stranger. Your outer loop generates rows, but you index them with `x`. Inner loop generates columns for each row, and you index it with `y`. There's general confusion over which axis is the X one and which is the Y one.

**EDIT**: Ah, I see the problem now. When `currentY == 0`, you print the numbers for the axis, and **also** print the dot.

Comment: There are actually two bugs here which cancel each other out: The one you pointed out with the comparison, and the fact the the `for` loops are backwards, so that the roles of `x` and `y` become reversed.

Comment: hi, its correct, you can see the result at http://ideone.com/WHVFOm, sorry for the naming confusion.

Comment: because for y, it starts from 0, thus -6 will cause it to start from -6 instead of -5, and end at 4 instead of 5

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you print the Y axis, you still print a dot, so everything to the right of the y axis is shifted over by 1.  You should have another `else` in there:

```
if( currentY == 0 )
{
    ....
}
else if (currentX == 0)  // <--- add an else there
{
    ....
}
else if ...
```